# Selecting RGB image pixels from an image using a mask

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a question like [Mask a 3d array with a 2d mask in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682284/mask-a-3d-array-with-a-2d-mask-in-numpy), but the answer from that isn't working for my issue; I am trying to get elements of an RGB image selected based on a 2d mask. I created a 2d mask with values of 1, on the elements that I want to preserve, with the rest being 0. I then want to apply this mask to an RGB image array and want to retain values only for elements that match the mask value of 1. I tried this code and it bombed. How do I select the pixels (and its values) based on the mask location. My bombed code based on the solution that is in the link is below.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

polygon = [(5,5), (10,5), (15,15), (2,15)]
width = 20
height = 20
# create a mask 
img = Image.new('L', (width, height), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = np.array(img)

mask = mask[:,:,np.newaxis] 

a_arr = np.arange(1200).reshape(20,20,3)  # create a test image type array
o_arr = np.ma.array(a_arr, mask=mask) 
print o_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a boolean array from your mask and index the image based on that array. Like so:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

polygon = [(5,5), (10,5), (15,15), (2,15)]
width = 20
height = 20
# create a mask 
img = Image.new('L', (width, height), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = np.array(img)
b_mask = mask.astype(bool)

a_arr = np.arange(1200).reshape(20,20,3)
o_arr = a_arr[b_mask]
print(o_arr)
```

### Update

Based on your comment have you tried just stacking the mask along the third dimension?

Instead of `mask = mask[:, :, np.newaxis]` use `mask = np.dstack((mask, mask, mask))`

Comment: Doing that identifies the element values, but I need the shape to remain the same as I am trying to identify regions with this. I am trying to use this for image blending.